# Displaying items in the jquery append() upon a drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a drop-down menu in the jquery append() function which adds contents to the row of a table whenever I click a button I  call "AddItem".

```
$('#tbody').append(`<tr id="R${++rowIdx}">

         <td class="row-index text-center">
            
        <select style="resize:none" id="item-deducted">
          <option id="window" value="Window">Window</option>
          <option id="door" value="Door">Door</option>
        </select>
      </td>


      <td>
          <select style="resize:none; display:none;" id="shapeDeducted" selected="none" >
            <option id="none" value="" selected></option>
            <option id="Normal" value="Normal (LxH)">Normal (LxH)</option>
            <option id="Triangular" value="Triangular">Triangular</option>
          </select>
      </td>

</tr>`);
```

I want to display option "Triangle" in the second select option whenever a user clicks or selects the option "Window" in the first select drop-down.

Comment: I added an answer below, initially 'Window' is the selected option, does that mean that by default the second dropdown should be shown anyway?

Comment: The below answer works perfectly except that when I had a new or several rows on the table only the first row gets populated with the choice "Triangle". The same happens if I had several rows first before selecting "Window" from the first drop-down which is in the first row. How can I have the same event(Any desired row to be filled with choice "Triangle") repeat itself in several rows of a column upon selecting the first row as "Window".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on change:  `$('#item-deducted').on('change')`.

```js
$('#tbody').append(`<tr id="R$">

         <td class="row-index text-center">
            
        <select style="resize:none" id="item-deducted">
          <option id="window" value="Window">Window</option>
          <option id="door" value="Door">Door</option>
        </select>
      </td>


      <td>
          <select style="resize:none; display:none;" id="shapeDeducted" selected="none" >
            <option id="none" value="" selected></option>
            <option id="Normal" value="Normal (LxH)">Normal (LxH)</option>
            <option id="Triangular" value="Triangular">Triangular</option>
          </select>
      </td>

</tr>`);

$('#item-deducted').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'Window'){
    $('#shapeDeducted').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tbody"></div>
```

Comment: The above answer works perfectly except that when I had a new or several rows on the table on the first row gets populated with choice "Triangle".

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is ```id``` based. So it will only work on 1 element.

Comment: The above answer works perfectly except that when I had a new or several rows on the table only the first row gets populated with the choice "Triangle". The same happens if I had several rows first before selecting "Window" from the first drop-down which is in the first row. How can I have the same event(Any desired row to be filled with choice "Triangle") repeat itself in several rows of a column upon selecting the first row as "Window".